# Kotlin OnClick Listener

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get Toast from UI defined in MainActivity and writing a code in Base Activity for onClick Listener. As per requirement I had define my base class as open but still I am not getting Toast

Here is code

BaseActivity

```
    open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val buttonClick= findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        buttonClick?.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this@BaseActivity, "Click...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
    class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.409" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="190dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can you tell what wrong with code how can I get a click from it

Comment: Did you forget to call `setContentView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're calling `val buttonClick= findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)` in `BaseActivity.onCreate`, which is called in `MainActivity.onCreate` **before** you call `setContentView`... So the view isn't initialized yet, and you aren't subscribed for click events.

You can attach `onClickListener` in `MainActivity`, or if you still want to do it from your `BaseActivity` you can make additional `initViews` method and call it after `setContentView`:

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        initViews()
    }
}



open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    } 

    protected fun initViews() {
        val buttonClick= findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        buttonClick?.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this@BaseActivity, "Click...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Personally, i think this is a bad approach. There is quite a possibility that you will forget to call `initViews` at some point that nothing will work, leading you to hours of investigation. Furthermore, if you want to fix that and define `initViews` as abstract, there is no point in having this in separate method in first place: just make variable abstract. See my answer for more details

Comment: While this is not the best approach, it doesn't force you to use `initViews`, while having `abstract val button` will force every activity that will extend `BaseActivity` to implement it. Furthermore, your question doesn't solve the core problem.

Comment: Hold on, the question itself intended, that he wants to have a base activity, which incapsulates some logic (every activity extended from that one should have the same logic), therefore "force every activity" is exactly what he wants

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the code of your listener in your `MainActivity`.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            val buttonClick= findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
            buttonClick?.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Click...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

    }
```

Because you are defining your listener in your BaseActivity's onCreate your `findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)` is effectively null due to the fact that `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` is called after.

Comment: It does solve the issue, however it does not suit logic he wanted to maintain: all activities inherited from base one should behave in the same way

Comment: @GeorgySavatkov yes that's correct although you have it answered already I'll just leave the credit to yours :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `setContentView` is only called after you've tried to set a listener to a nonexistent view.

One possible solution would be to only try to add the click listener (without the ?.) after you've called an abstract method that tries to set the content view.

```
abstract class BaseActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    abstract val layoutId: Int

    override fun onCreate(bundle: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(bundle)
         setContentView(layoutId) 
         button.setOnClickListener {
            ...
```

Answer (score -1):

The thing is that you are trying to access you button in `BaseActivity` class, whilst your layout is loaded only inside `MainActivity`. Therefore the button can not be found. The solution would be:

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   abstract val buttonClick: Button

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       buttonClick.setOnClickListener {
           Toast.makeText(this@BaseActivity, "Click...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
  }
}

class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {
   override val buttonClick: Button
        get() = button // Kotlin view binding

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
   }
}
```

What has been done: we have defined an abstract button and assigned a click listener to it. Thus, the logic of click handling stayed in base activity, while MainActivity just defines a view (R.id.button, via kotlin view binding) to operate on.

Comment: Wait I notice a slight problem here > `BaseActivity.onCreate()` will be called first before `MainActivity.onCreate()` which stills make buttonClick null.

Answer (score -1):

Use it 
`Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`